# Using local variable of a method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know how can we read the value of a local variable in another class / instance of a class in javascript.

eg:

I have a method in a class :

```
myClass1.prototype.myMethod0 = function()

{
 this._myVar = null; //initialize this._myVar
}

myClass1.prototype.myMethod1 = function(list)
{
 this._myVar = msg.list;
}
```

and

```
myClass1.prototype.myMethod2 = function()
{
 //do something 
// and update the list like say:

list1 = this._myVar; //access the this_myVar.

}
```

and in my another calss say,

```
myClass2.prototype.myMethod = function()
{
 //call the class1's method here..

myClass1.prototype.myMethod2();

}
```

`myMethod2` is a callback and i bind it in `myClass2`.

It means, actually, `myMethod2` is being called like this: `myClass1.callback();`

But my problem is , when i call `myClass1.prototype.myMethod2();`, the `list1 = this._myVar;` is not getting updated and it is becoming `undefined`. I am not getting the fix for the same.

The problem is the variable, "this._myVar" is "undefined" in myMethod2 of myclass1

Comment: Have you called method1 before and set this_myVar?

Comment: Where do you declare `this_myVar` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do is possible but not the way you did it:

1. Without the `var` keyword, a variable is not local but global. So your code actually created a **global** variable `this_myVar` which is shared by all JavaScript code on the same page.
2. `list1` will be undefined if `myMethod1()` was never called.

See [here for an introduction into JavaScript OO programming][1].

**[EDIT]** I see you updated your question and the variable is now accessed via `this`. The automatic variable `this` is only assigned when the function is called as a "method".

`myClass1.prototype.myMethod2()` will call the original definition and `this` will be undefined.

You have to use code like this:

```
var inst = new myClass1();
inst.myMethod2();
```

Inside of `myMethod2`, the variable `this` will have the same value as `inst` if you call it like that.

**[EDIT2]** If you want to access instance properties, then you **must** call `myMethod2()` via an instance of `myClass1` - JavaScript doesn't try to read your mind what your code might mean.

So at the time when you want to call any method of `myClass1`, you must have an instance of it. Try to create one in `myClass2`:

```
var myClass2 = function() {
    this.inst1 = new myClass1();
}

myClass2.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    this.inst1.myMethod2();
}
```

Alternatively, you will have to pass the instance to the method:

```
myClass2.prototype.myMethod = function(inst1) {
    inst1.myMethod2();
}
```

But if you call `myMethod2()` like any other global method, `this` won't have any useful value. There is way to say "When I call a function with a prefix of `myClass1.prototype.`, then look for an instance of `myClass1` and put that into `this`". What should JavaScript do when there are 15 instances of this type? Select one by random?

Comment: But I am calling myMethod1() and then, a call to myMethod2 is happening. yet, somehow, it's value is becoming "undefined"!

Comment: is there any other solution for this? I will have to call it as "myClass1.prototype.myMethod2();" only and also, myMethod2 is a callback.

Comment: Call it with the list as argument: `myClass1.prototype.myMethod2(this.list1);`

Comment: but list1 should be update with this._myVar., which is in myClass1

Answer (score 0):

Here this_myVar is a local variable inside the function, so once you come out of the function

its value is lost.

So you will get an undefined value.

In order to retain the value you have top declare this_myVar as a datamember inside class.